# Не работает SetConsoleOutputCP и SetConsoleCP

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. В прошлом году взялся за изучение C++. Для этого дела использовал Microsoft Visual Studio Express. После новогодних праздников решил продолжить изучение языка (за это время успел переустановить ОС). По быстрому поставил себе компилятор g++ и IDE Geany. Для проверки корректной работы моих новых инструментов, решил набрать простую программу.

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <cstdlib>;
#include <windows.h>;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    cout << "Привет, мир!\n";
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

И на тебе, кириллица в консоле не вывелась:

[image: img]

В Visual Studio всё работало. В чём проблема?

Comment: Клюцни правой кнопкой на консоль-> заходиш в свойства->вкладку шрифт ->и меняеш ево на Сonsolas либо на иной другой.

Comment: блин немного не успел

Comment: Что вы не успели? А что такое - "клюцни"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо редактировать нажал удалить, сорри.

Варианта три

- Не компилируется - SetConsole* MS
     функции не обязательно будут
     поддерживаться другим компилятором.
- Если эти функции имеются в библиотеке идущей с компилятором, не 
     обязательно будут обеспечивать то
     же поведение программы.

Вообще эти два варианта справедливы для любых не входящих в стандарт функций.

- SetConsole* воздействует только на
     Unicode шрифты, поэтому необходимо
     задать в консоли для отображению
     именно такой шрифт (обычно Lucida
     Console)

Comment: IMHO gcc/g++ не используют в своих библиотеках аналоги функций MS, а вызывают их непосредственно из системных библиотек. 

Поскольку программа слинковалась (и отработала), то варианты 1 и 2 можно сразу отбросить.

--

Ответ про шрифт правильный. 

--

В русской семерке есть (по крайней мере у меня) еще один *"глюк"*. 

После установки надо войти в "панель управления"->"язык и региональные стандарты"->"дополнительно" и в пункте "текущий язык программ, не поддерживающих Юникод" **2 раза изменить язык**.

Первый раз на любой, потом перезагрузиться и **заменить на русский**.

Потом работает.

Comment: если программа слинковалась - не позволяет отбросить пункт 2, и там "унутре" может реализовываться очень разное поведение от вызова системных функций или собственной реализации, до например какого-либо макроса. Я занудничаю, потому что не люблю такие функции и обычно не рекомендую их использовать.

Comment: @Mirdin, а Вы просто посмотрите в /MinGW/include

    wincon.h:183:BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleOutputCP(UINT);

и все станет более понятно.

Comment: @avp я ими не пользовался фиг знает сколько времени, и сомнительно что воспользуюсь в ближайшем будущем. Понадобиться - посмотрю, а так...

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, функция SetConsoleOutputCP(1251) прекрасно работает и переводит консоль в кодировку 1251, однако исходный код сохранён в UTF-8.
Решение: в текстовом редакторе (настройках IDE) выбрать кодировку Windows-1251.